# Manually overwriting the results of SQL query in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I came across a very strange situation and I hope maybe you guys can provide some clarity.

I run an sql query in access and get some results. if I enter into the results window and manually alter a record, then re-run the query, the result of the query will show my alteration instead of the correct value. how can this be?

Moreover, the field I alter is simply an attribute from a table, so re-running should retrieve the value from the original table, instead on my alteration into the query, right?

thanks!

Comment: When asking SQL questions, you should always post the sql.

Comment: "simply an attribute from a table" ? You definitely need to expand on this with a reproduceable example

Answer (score 1):

when you're using access, as long as the query isn't complicated with UNION and lots of other fun stuff, the the queries that are returned are not 'static' but 'dynamic': any changes you make to the cells directly edit the DB. Yes, the query is retrieving the value from the table but will also save any changes you make back to the table.

If you run the query programatically you can specify whether to make it read-only or not but the results window directly edits the tables for most queries.